# Why am i getting "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement"

Tags: python

I am writing a code to play lucky sevens. I get the error right after "import random" when running the module in IDLE. I can type "import random" directly into IDLE and it will work fine but I cant run the whole module, which means I can't test the entire code.

Heres the code:

```
import random

count = 0
pot = int(input("How much money would you like to start with in your pot? "))
if pot>0 and pot.isdigit():
    choice = input("Would you like to see the details of where all of your money went? yes, or no? ")
    if choice ==  ("yes", "Yes", "YES", "ya", "Ya", "y", "Y")
        while pot>0:
            roll1 = random.randint(1, 7)
            roll2 = random.randint(1, 7)
            roll = (roll1)+(roll2)
            count += 1
            maxpot = max(pot)
            if roll == 7:
                pot +=4
                print("Your rolled "+str(roll1)" and "+str(roll2)". That's "+str(roll)"! You get $4! Your pot is now at $"+str(pot))
            else:
                pot -= 1
                print("Your rolled "+str(roll1)" and "+str(roll2)". That's "+str(roll)". You loose a dollar... Your pot is now at $"+str(pot))
        print("Oh no! Your pot is empty! It took "+str(count)" rounds! Your maximum pot was $"+str(maxpot)"!")
    elif choice == ("no", "No", "No", "n", "N"):
        while pot>0:
            roll1 = random.randint(1, 7)
            roll2 = random.randint(1, 7)
            roll = (roll1)+(roll2)
            count += 1
            maxpot = max(pot)
            if roll == 7:
                pot +=4
            else:
                pot -= 1
        print("Oh no! Your pot is empty! It took "+str(count)" rounds! Your maximum pot was $"+str(maxpot)"!")
    else:
        print("You did not enter 'yes' or 'no'. Be sure and type either 'yes' or 'no' exactly like that. Lets try agian!")
        restart_program
else:
    print("Please enter a positive dollar amount.")
    restart_program
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if choice == ("yes", "Yes", "YES", "ya", "Ya", "y", "Y")
#         ^ you probably should use `in` here.
#                                                       ^ and you forgot a ':'.
```

---

```
print("Your rolled "+str(roll1)" and "+str(roll2)". That's "+str(roll)"! You get $4! Your pot is now at $"+str(pot))
#                              ^ you forgot a `+`.                    ^ here as well.
```

---

Besides the syntax,

- It seems you've redefined the function `max`, because with the built-in definition `max(pot)` can't be run. It is a very bad idea to define a function that overlaps with the name of a built-in.
- If `restart_program` is a function, you should call it as `restart_program()`, otherwise it is a statement that does nothing.

Comment: or use if choice[0].lower == 'y' to just check if the first character is a Y in upper or lower case.

Answer (score 0):

- Several times there is no "+" when concenating strings in your print(...) commands (s. answer of KennyTM, but they are missing in every print()-command.)
- pot.isdigit() is nonsense. pot is already an int and therefore function isdigit is no member of int.
- restart_programm is not defined (s. KennyTM)
- max(pot) (s. KennyTM)